# Why Does Open Street Maps (OSM) use PostgreSQL databases?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap

Over the last few months, I've been using the openstreetmap-tile-server on GitHub ([link here](https://github.com/Overv/openstreetmap-tile-server)) to render OSM tiles from a Docker container. The tile server uses a PostgreSQL database to store its data. From doing more research into creating my own OSM tiles and my own tile server, a lot of tutorials mention using a PostgreSQL database.

Why is this? Why not use an SQL database such as MySQL instead? What can be gained / is gained from using PostgreSQL rather than a different SQL database for a dataset such as the openstreetmap data?

---

EDIT: Edited question, to indicate that I'm comparing Postgres to other SQL databases.

Comment: [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org) *is* an SQL database in the same way that MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, ... are SQL databases. There are also standard GIS extensions to PostgreSQL that might be useful in OSM.

Comment: just a guess: it's mature, multi-platform, open source, free, and with a strong GIS component (PostGIS)

Comment: @muistooshort I had always thought that PostgreSQL was a completely separate database, akin to how MongoDB and SQL are separate databases. It sounds like this is incorrect?

Comment: SQL is not a database, it's a database interface *language*.  As such it is used by many different databases.  Maybe you're getting confused by Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: @JGH Do other SQL-based databases not have GIS components? I know that Postgres is an 'object-relational database system', is this significant for making it preferable for GIS integrations?

Comment: @Max: yes that's incorrect. The `SQL` in PostgreSQL refers to the fact that it's using SQL as it's query language. One reason why OpenStreetMap uses Postgres, that with PostGIS (a GIS extension for Postgres) it offers probably one of the best GIS support in the relational world (=SQL databases).

Comment: About the only part of Postgres that is object orientated is the ```TABLE INHERITS``` in ```CREATE TABLE```. In the way back past there was rumblings of more to come, but there turned out to be no real need. GIS integration is there because Postgres support geometric types and PostGIS built on top of that. Also because it has a BSD license that does not restrict people working with it.

Answer (score 9):

Originally MySQL was actually used for the main internal OSM database that stores actual OSM data and is queried and modified via the OSM API. For tile rendering and other purposes the internal raw format is never used though, instead OSM data exported as compressed XML or in more compact binary PBF format is imported into a database schema more suitable for further processing.

Typically this is done with either the "imposm" or the "osm2pgsql" tool, with the PostgreSQL/PostGIS combination as the RDBMS of choice, as it provides the most powerful GIS feature set, at least in the free & open source world.

The main OSM database is an exception as any queries on it are always retrieving data for a rectangular area only, and so GIS extensions are actually not needed, having the coordinates stored as simple numeric data is sufficient in this case. Eventually it was decided to switch that to PostgreSQL, too, to reduce the number of different components to maintain in the openstreetmap.org site setup.

In theory you could also use other RDBMS with GIS support, too, e.g. the SpatiaLite variant of SQLite, or MariaDB/MySQL, but compared to PostgreSQL/PostGIS setup they have their disadvantages:

E.g. SpatiaLite is only good as long as there's only one thread accessing the data, with concurrent access it doesn't scale well at all.

And MariaDB and MySQL only really implement more or less the bare minimum of the OpenGIS SQL specs, end even that only really materialized over the last years. Feature wise both are still more than a decade behind PostGIS at least.

Disclaimer: even I, although working for MariaDB Corp, and having worked for MySQL AB before, in total for over a decade, have always recommended to use PostGIS over MariaDB or MySQL for GIS applications unless someone was bound to MariaDB or MySQL for other reasons already.